# haml editing on gEdit, any way to auto indent?

Tags: haml, gedit

I'm using gEdit to edit haml files and the auto indenting feature seems to work when i'm writing one line after another, but when I go and clear out a exisiting element (a div or a class) the rest of the code below doesn't adjust itself. Suppose this is my code

```
.rightside
  .container
    %ul
      %li hello
      %li world
```

Now is there any way (using some plugin) through which when I delete .rightside, the rest of the code moves to left by two spaces? I now have to manually erase the space on every line. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the block underneath the tag in question and use Shift-Tab or Ctrl-Shift-T to un-indent the text, assuming you have gedit set to use 2 spaces for tabs.

I have also installed the multi-edit plugin. This gives me multiple carets at which points any edits i make will be duplicated. In this case, I can just position the cursor at the top of that block, use the Ctrl-PgDown key shortcut to select the whole block, and then hit delete a couple times.